# How do I replace IDs from multiple columns with the related data from the same external table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I have two MySQL tables ( simplified ).

Table 'words' contains 'id' and 'word' fields. Table 'entities' has an 'id' field ( for each entity ) and then multiple columns that each contain word_id's from the words table ( word_id_0, word_id_1, word_id_2, etc. ).

I'd like to dump a bunch of rows from the 'entities' table and replace the word_id's with the words. Is there an easy way to do this with SQL?

```
go from: 1, 234, 456, 567
to: 1, word_234, word_456, word_567
```

Normally I'd join the two tables and then select the 'word' instead of the 'word_id'. I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to do this without a ton of nested join queries.

Answer (score 1):

table `words` contains columns `id` and `word`

table `entities` contains columns `id` and `word_id_0` and `word_id_1` and I am adding `word_0` and `word_1` to hold the words themselves. (You can add additional columns below - this is just a proof of concept.)

```
UPDATE entities 
LEFT JOIN words w0 ON (w0.id = entities.word_id_0)
LEFT JOIN words w1 ON (w1.id = entities.word_id_1)
SET word_0 = w0.word, word_1 = w1.word
```

If word_id_n is already a CHAR or a VARCHAR then you could put the word directly in there, but it just bothers me to have a non-id string in a column labeled as an ID.

SOURCE: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/ and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html